# removing an entity from database symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to remove an entity related with one to one relation to an other entity. but I always failed oon it. This the code, I have tried:

```
$adminid=$centrex->getDefadmin()->getId();
$defadmin = $em->getRepository('TelnOperatorBundle:Defadmin')->find($adminid);
$em->remove($defadmin);
    $em->flush();
```

Could anybody help me?
The problem is as follows :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM DefAdmin WHERE id = ?' with params {"1":"5"}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`symfony`.`centrex`, CONSTRAINT `FK_63C80A4692343E35` FOREIGN KEY (`defadmin_id`) REFERENCES `defadmin` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Doctrine Documentation.
On working with associations:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html

Especially cascade on remove would be of interest for you, see point 8.6 on the linked document.

Answer (score 0):

`onDelete=Cascade` add this on your entity